# How does `CI=true` affect the `npm install` command?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having trouble finding good documentation on how the `CI=true` effects the `npm install` command.

How is `CI=true npm install` different from `npm install`.
Does the `CI=true` even effect the install?

I tried it locally and it does *NOT* cause it to behave like `npm ci`. I tried running it without the `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file present. It created the lock file.

Also, is there a difference between

```
CI=true npm install
```

and

```
CI=true 
npm install
```

and

```
export CI=true 
npm install
```

Comment: It seems to also be used for certain test frameworks to change the behavior of the tests from human run to machine run.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting the `CI` environment variable to `true` effects how npm gathers usage data.

How it effects npm is explained in the [Does npm send any information about me back to the registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/registry.html#does-npm-send-any-information-about-me-back-to-the-registry) section of the docs *(For convenience, I've provided a verbatim copy of that section below)*. Consider particularly the description about the `Npm-In-CI` header.

In summary, setting `CI=true` causes npm to set the `Npm-In-CI` header to `true`, thus as a result the data gathered (by npm) assumes the package(s) are being installed via a *"build farm"*, (i.e. for **C**ontinuous **I**ntegration purposes), instead of a *"human"*.

The following is what is stated in the docs at the aforementioned link:

> **Does npm send any information about me back to the registry?**
>
> Yes.
>
> When making requests of the registry npm adds two headers with information about your environment:
>
> - **`Npm-Scope`** – If your project is scoped, this header will contain its scope. In the future npm hopes to build registry features that use this information to allow you to customize your experience for your organization.
> - **`Npm-In-CI`** – Set to “true” if npm believes this install is running in a continuous integration environment, “false” otherwise. This is detected by looking for the following environment variables: `CI`, `TDDIUM`, `JENKINS_URL`, `bamboo.buildKey`. If you’d like to learn more you may find the [original PR](https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-client/pull/129) interesting. This is used to gather better metrics on how npm is used by humans, versus build farms.

---

With regards to the specific part of your question, i.e.

> Does the `CI=true` even effect the install?

Generally *"No"*, there is *no* notable difference to the resultant installation by npm with or without `CI=true`.

However, a possible scenario whereby the installation of a package by npm could/may be effected, is if a package author defined a [`postinstall`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) script in *package.json* that performed different conditional logic if/when the `CI` environment variable is set to `true`.

---

Regarding the last part of your question, i.e.

> Also, is there a difference between ...

The accepted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables) addresses that.

In summary;

- Your first two commands are similar - they both set the environment variable for the current shell only.
- However your last example that utilizes [`export`](https://ss64.com/bash/export.html) sets the environment variable for the current shell and all processes started from the current shell.